# Where is the PEVerify equivalent in.NET Core for Mac and Linux?

Tags: .net, .net-core

In .Net Framework the PEVerify determines whether the IL code of a .Net module meets type safety requirements.

What is the equivalent tool in .NET Core that produces the same kind of verification?

Comment: Just keep using PEVerify, .NETCore assemblies are not different.

Comment: @HansPassant Where can I get the PEVerify for Mac or Linux?

Comment: From a Unix dev that contributes to open source and has an itch he can't scratch.  Get source from the SSCLI20 project, clr/src/tools/peverify directory.  We'll volunteer you, looks like [matty-hall might want to help as well](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/2527).

Answer (score 2):

The official alternative to PEVerify.exe for .net core apps and beyond is to use ILVerify.  You can install it via the command line:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ilverify
```

Sample provided by Microsoft:

```
dotnet ilverify hello.dll -r "c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.12\*.dll"
```

Note that unlike PEVerify, you *must* supply *all* the references on the command line (including the framework assemblies), so if the assembly you are trying to verify references other assemblies in your project, you'll need to reference those too by adding more `-r` switches to the command.

Official documentation [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/coreclr/tools/ILVerify/README.md)

Thanks to Hans Passant for the five year old comment to the question that led me to this solution.